# How to convert from Pandas' DatetimeIndex to DataFrame in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
# Get the min and max dates
minDate, maxDate = df2.select(f.min("MonthlyTransactionDate"), f.max("MonthlyTransactionDate")).first()
d = pd.date_range(start=minDate, end=maxDate, freq='MS')    

tmp = pd.Series(d)
df3 = spark.createDataFrame(tmp)
```

I have checked tmp and a I have a pandas dataframe of a list of dates.
I then check df3 but it looks like lit's just an empty list:

```
++ 
|| 
++ 
|| 
|| 
|| 
|| 
|| 
|| 
|| 
||
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case `d` is `DatetimeIndex`. What you can do is create pandas DataFrame from `DatetimeIndex` and then convert Pandas DF to spark DF. PFB Sample code.

#### 1. Create DatetimeIndex

```python
import pandas as pd
d = pd.date_range('2018-12-01', '2019-01-02', freq='MS')
```

#### 2. Create Pandas DF.

```python
p_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

#### 3. Create Spark DataFrame.

```python
spark.createDataFrame(p_df).show()
```

Answer (score 3):

`d` is a `DatetimeIndex`, not a pandas data frame here. You need to convert it to data frame first which can be done using `to_frame` method:

```py
d = pd.date_range('2018-10-10', '2018-12-15', freq='MS')
spark.createDataFrame(d).show()
++
||
++
||
||
++

spark.createDataFrame(d.to_frame()).show()
+-------------------+
|                  0|
+-------------------+
|2018-11-01 00:00:00|
|2018-12-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

now we can use pyspark pandas.
https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/04/pandas-api-on-upcoming-apache-spark-3-2.html

import pyspark.pandas as pd

so we can use .to_spark() after .to_dataframe() to be pyspark's dataframe.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.to_spark.html?highlight=to_spark#pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.to_spark

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).